# Flask / SQLAlchemy - one-to-one relationship syntax

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask / SQLAlchemy model called Subscription, which is associated with many other models (Subscribers, Payments, etc).  I now have to pair two Subscriptions, where one Subscription is sometimes called a 'benefactor' with respect to another Subscription called its 'recipient'.  This is an optional one-to-one self-referential model.

When I try the following:

```
class Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Subscription(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'subscriptions'
    benefactor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subscriptions.id'))
    recipient = relationship('Subscription', uselist=False, backref='benefactor')
```

I get the error:

```
Subscription.recipient and back-reference Subscription.benefactor are both
of the same direction symbol('ONETOMANY').  Did you mean to set remote_side
on the many-to-one side ?
```

This works fine with just the benefactor_id definition, but breaks on the relationship declaration.  Any suggestions?  I don't understand this error--from my reading of the documentation, uselist=False should prevent this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out, but am not particularly satisfied with the solution.

First, I found that I had to repeat the 'id' attribute in both the base and derived classes.  I couldn't move it from the base class because it is referenced by base class methods and numerous other derived classes, and at the same time I could not reference the base class declaration from the derived class and so had to re-declare it (anyone have a better solution)?  I hope I haven't broken anything in SQLAlchemy - at least all my tests pass, in spite of how little I like this solution.

Second, to make a one-to-one self-referential connection work, I declared the relationship as shown below.

```
class Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Subscription(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subscriptions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    benefactor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subscriptions.id'))
    recipient = relationship('Subscription', uselist=False,
                              backref=db.backref('benefactor', remote_side=id))
```

Answer (score -1):

The error says that you need to set the `remote_side` keyword for the relationship. Have you tried setting it like this?

```
class Subscription(Base):

__tablename__ = 'subscriptions'
benefactor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subscriptions.id'))
recipient= relationship(
    'Subscription',
    uselist=False,
    remote_side=[id],
    backref='benefactor'
)
```

Comment: It seems that this field isn't available for reference at this point because the table is self-referential: "AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id'"

Comment: You don't have an id in your Subscriptions table?

Comment: I would have thought I should use benefactor_id.  I do have an id in my base class:
     class Base(db.Model):
         __abstract__ = True
         id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

Comment: benefactor_id is a foreign key. Try adding an id field to your model and see if it works.

Comment: I do have an id in my model; I have updated the original question to clarify that.  My apologies for not including the Base class decl.  I did try reference id as well - the error when I declare "    recipient = relationship('Subscription', uselist=False, backref='benefactor', remote_side='subscriptions.id')
" is:  AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id'